Is every strong deformation retract of a manifold a very strong deformation retract?
Given a strong deformation retract of smooth manifolds $N\subset M$, $p:M\rightarrow N$ together with a homotopy relative to $N$ that witnesses the strong deformation retract $H:M\times [0,1]\rightarrow M$.
There is the notion of a very strong deformation retract which I have only seen in this paper. A strong deformation retract is a very strong deformation retract if the homotpy respects the fibers of $p$ i.e.
$H(H(m,t),1)=p(m)$ for all $m\in M$ and $t\in[0,1].$ This means that the homotpy moves points only within their fiber of the map $p$.
Clearly not every map $p$ can have a homotopy that satisfies this. For example if we have a square with one side missing and pick one adjacent side as a subspace then the obvious projection is a strong deformation retract but not a very strong deformation retract because the homotopy has to move points through other fibers than their own. But in this case we can modify the map to send everything except the one side to a point, which then is a very strong deformation retract.
My question is now: Is very strong deformation retract of smooth manifolds a very strong deformation retract? Meaning that we can potentially pick another retraction map that witnesses this fact.

I don't understand your example. Take [0,1)×[0,1] and let p(x,y)=x. This is a square with a side removed and p is a very strong def retraction. Clearly you must mean something else.

I mean only the boundary of the square without the inside.
